# What kinds of exceptions might String(contentsOf url:URL) throw?

Tags: swift

I'm in that stage where I'm refactoring a prototype to be more flexible. Which means I want to add in error handling. My app relies pretty heavily on String(contentsOf:url) which, as with any action that deals with files, is error-prone. However the signature for the init method in question simply reads:

```
init(contentsOf url: URL) throws
```

So I know it throws… but what does it throw specifically? I'm not sure I understand how to handle errors when I don't know what errors I may be handed. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1779753-init) doesn't say anything either. I'm stumped?

Comment: You should no be using that initializer. Use URLSession to load data.

Comment: Isn't URL session for downloading network data? I'm just loading a local file.

Comment: OK, for local files it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init(contentsOf:)` comes from Foundation's `NSString` API — as such, like all Foundation APIs, it throws an `NSError` which describes the error. You can catch it like any other error:

```
do {
    let str = String(contentsOf: theLocalURL)
    // ...
} catch {
    // Present `error.localizedDescription` to the user to let them know what went wrong
}
```

Since the error is an `NSError`, you can also catch it as such to inspect its `code`/`userInfo`:

```
do {
    // Same as above
} catch let error as NSError {
    // Inspect what went wrong.
}
```

As for which specific codes you might expect, look at the error codes starting with `NSFile`... in the [`NSError Codes` list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1448136-nserror_codes). Common codes might be `NSFileReadNoPermissionError` or `NSFileReadNoSuchFileError` if the file doesn't exist, among others.

In general, though, you should display the `localizedDescription` of the error to your user and abort the operation or try again.