# Swift: How to know the types of errors a throwing function throws?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I'm pretty new on Swift so maybe this is a silly question for most of you.

Consider this method:

```
func load() throws {
  let data = try Data(contentsOf: storeURL)

  items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
}
```

This method can throw due errors in the `Data` reading, or due errors on the JSON decoding operation. I would like to know the possible reasons (errors) they could fail for, for example

```
do {
  try load()
} catch FileNotFoundError {
  // do something in case file doesn't exist
} catch InvalidJSONFormatError {
  // do something in case file is not JSON
} catch {
  // do something for all other cases
}
```

*(The `FileNotFoundError` and `InvalidJSONFormatError` are not actual Swift errors, I just put them there as placeholders for what I'm trying to explain).*

The problem is that I don't know what kind/types of errors `try Data(contentsOf:)` can throw and what kind/types of errors `try JSONDecoder().decode()` can throw. For example, I would like to know what is the error `Data()` throws in cases in which the file is not found, or what other errors it can throw.

I was looking at the `Data` initializer doc but no clue about what types of errors it throws https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/3126626-init

Thank you.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44741741/5133585), foundation APIs like `Data.init` (`NSData.init`) throws `NSError`s. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55389926/5133585) shows you what errors `JSONDecoder` throws. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really. I know that `Data.init` could fail (since is a throwing function) but what are the possible reasons of that failure? You say that it throws a `NSError` but that's  a generic error, it doesn't allow me to take specific actions for each possible reason of failure.

Comment: Have you checked out the [NSError codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1448136-nserror_codes), which was one of the links in the first link? You can check the `code` property of the `NSError` against each of those codes. Have you actually read the first link?

Comment: Ok, the information you provided to me could be taken as an answer to the specific problem that I posted as an example. But my question is kind of generic. Now you answered about the possible errors for `Data.init` and `JSONDecoder` that's ok. But tomorrow maybe I'm gonna work with `FileManager.createDirectory()` or any other function/method and I'm gonna have the same question again: "what errors does it throws?". From the huge list of NSError codes, which of them are thrown by X function? Apple docs is not to clear about it. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Indeed, Apple does not say, but that's not how this works, is it? The way this works is: you have a requirement of "I want to handle a particular of error (e.g. file not found) in a particular way", so you go look up the code for that particular error (`NSFileNoSuchFileError`) and write your code. It is none of your business *whether* a particular error is thrown by a function. That is implementation detail.

Comment: So long story short, use your common sense. :D

Comment: `Data` would likely throw `CocoaError` and for `JSONDecoder` it's `DecodingError`